# Adding sums in a loop while also using the def function

Tags: python-3.x, function, count, sum

I am working on a function that sums up the amount of positive and negative numbers a user inputs. It has to be in a loop and has to have two functions(on for pos, one for neg) to return True or False. I have tried everything and am so lost and don't even know where to start anymore. This is what I have so far:

```
pos = 0
neg = 0 
num = int(input("Please enter a positive or negative number. Or 0 to quit"))

while num > -100 or num < 100:
    num = int(input("Please enter a positive or negative number. Or 0 to quit"))

if num > 100 or num < -100:
    print("Please only enter integers between -100 to 100")
    num = int(input("Please enter a positive or negative number. Or 0 to quit"))

elif num == 0:
    print("Here is your summary: ")
    print("You entered: ", pos, "positives number(s) and", neg, "negative number(s)")
    

def if_positive(pos):
    if num > 0: 
        pos = pos + 1

def if_negative(neg):
    if num < 0:
        neg = neg + 1

if_positive(pos)
if_negative(neg)
```

Every time I try something, I get one part correct and then the other wrong. Python for Everybody hasn't helped at all and I've done hours of research and nothing helps. Please help me. Every time I post a question on here it gets removed! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I am just trying to ask a simple question :( So I will try for the third time!

Comment: Don't worry bro... see my answer

Comment: Rather than reposting the same question repeatedly, I think you should take a look at how to write a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do it as follow
Lets have while loop then if the num is zero just break it otherwise check the  conditions
I have added two lists but if you just count how many numbers positive and negative then you don't need lists you can use integer count variables

```py
postive_numbers =[]
negative_numbers =[]
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a positive or negative number. Or 0 to quit\n Enter the number: "))
    if num>100 or num < -100:
        print("Please only enter integers between -100 to 100")
        continue
    if num == 0:
        print("Here is your summary:\n ")
        print("You entered: \npositives number(s) {} \nnegative number(s){} ".format(len(postive_numbers),len(negative_numbers)))
        break
    elif num< 0:
        negative_numbers.append(num)
        
    else:
        postive_numbers.append(num)
```

Comment: Thank you so much rcvaram!!! Both answers helped me understand the formatting so much better :) Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say your questions are being removed because they sound like school assignments, and people tend to sour a little at the idea of people going to StackOverflow to have others do their homework for them. That said, it seems to me like you've put in a good-faith effort based on what you've already written, and there's nothing wrong with asking for help when you don't understand something after trying to figure it out yourself.

Try this:

```
def is_positive(number):
    """
    This could be shortened to simply:
    `return number > 0`
    """
    if number > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def is_negative(number):
    """
    Similarly, this could be shortened to:
    `return number < 0`
    """
    if number < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


n_positive = 0
n_negative = 0

while True:
    num_entered = int(input("Please enter a positive or negative number. Or 0 to quit"))
    if not -100 < num_entered < 100:
        print("Please only enter integers between -100 to 100")
    elif is_positive(num_entered):
        # this is a shortcut for `n_positive = n_positive + 1`
        n_positive += 1    
    elif is_negative(num_entered):
        n_negative += 1
    else:
        break
        
print("Here is your summary:")
# this is equivalent to what you had in your question, but uses "f-strings", 
# which were implemented in Python 3.6 and are super convenient
print(f"You entered {n_positive} positive number(s) and {n_negative} negative number(s)")
```

A few extra notes you might find helpful:

- `if not -100 < num_entered < 100:` is equivalent to `if num > 100 or num < -100:`, but just a cleaner way of writing it
- `while True` is an idiom in Python that essentially means "keep looping forever until I break out of it or exit the program."  From the code you had written, it seems like you want to keep allowing the user to input numbers until they enter "`0 to quit`".  That's the condition upon which you want to `break` out of the loop.
- "`def`" itself isn't a function -- `def` is a *keyword* that *defines* a function, which is a snippet of code that performs a single task that can be re-used later.  You said your two functions needed to return `True` or `False`.  In Python, the `return` keyword causes a function to exit and "return" the value specified.

  - This is why you're able to use those pre-defined functions directly in the the `if`  and `elif` statements later.  You can think of the way "`if`" works as taking the code between `if` and `:` and evaluating it.  If it evaluates to `True`, then the block of code inside (i.e., indented under) the `if` statement is executed and any `elif` or `else` statements you may or may not have after that are skipped.  Or, if it evaluates to `False`, then Python "moves on," and if you have an `elif` statement after the `if`, it repeats the same process there.  Finally, if neither or `if` or `elif` blocks evaluate to `True` and you have an `else` block, *that* code is run.

    This is a very long way of saying that in your case, the logical flow is: "if the number isn't between -100 and 100, remind the user of the acceptable range of values.  Otherwise, if the number `is_positive`, add 1 to the running count of positive numbers entered.  Or, if the number `is_negative`, add 1 to the count of negative numbers.  Otherwise, *the only remaining possibility is that the number is 0*, so the user is finished entering numbers and we should `break` out of the loop and show them their summary.

Hope this helps! Feel free to comment with any other questions you have.

Comment: Thank you so much Paxton! I always try to do the assignments first before I ask for help! I want to do this for a career so I definitely know I need to be able to truly understand the material and not just find easy answers. You helped a lot and I was able to figure it out!!! So grateful :)<3